# Hide navigation menu after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a navigation menu that works well, however it stays on until the mouse moves out of the dropdown.

I already have a function that displays content in another `<div>` (otherDiv) when we select something in the menu and I'm trying to have it hide the menu at the same time.

```js
function go(obj) {
  var page = obj.href;
  document.getElementById('otherDiv').innerHTML = '<img src="' + page + '"></img>'
  return false;
  document.getElementById('menu1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu3').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu4').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu5').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu6').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
    .drpbtn {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 12px 25px;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: auto;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #403e3e;
 color: #ffffff;
 float: left;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.drpbtn:hover {
 background-color: #00b3be;
}

.drpbtn:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #fafafa;
 width: 290px;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: -4.7em;
 margin-top: 0.89em;
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {
 background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

.dropdown-content li {
 display: block;
}

.li-drop {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #000000;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 11px 13px;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="drpbtn">Menu 1
      <ul id="menu1">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 1</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 2</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 3</div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="drpbtn">Menu 2
      <ul id="menu2">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 1</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 2</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 3</div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="drpbtn">Menu 3
      <ul id="menu3">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 1</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 2</div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="li-drop">
            <a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">
              <div class="div-drop">Choice 3</div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: I see you are relatively new to Stack Overflow and may not be aware of how things work, but if you feel someone has answered your question, please award that answer as correct by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function go(obj) {
  var page = obj.href;
  document.getElementById('otherDiv').innerHTML = '<img src="' + page + '"></img>'
  document.getElementById('menu1').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu2').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu3').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu4').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu5').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('menu6').style.display = "none";
  return false;
}
```

I believe your return is in the wrong place. If you return in the middle of the function, nothing after will be executed. Your code should be as I have it above.

Comment: I can't do much else without more code....

How does the display get reset once you set display to none?

Comment: The display is fine, it's just the the dropdown won't appear anymore after the first click. I added some of the CSS that I used.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. You are setting it's display to none in your code on the click. You will have to set it back so it displays again somewhere.

Comment: Oh got it! Thanks this will help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

well ... if you are using a jquery here is an example how to hide navigation menu after a single click outside the menu. Just add a `class="menu"` to your `<div>` with `id="menu"`, try the sample and build your own logic based on parents class names ...

```
<script>
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        var $e = $(e.target);
        if (!$e.parents().hasClass('menu')) {
           $('.menu').css({ 'display': 'none' });
        }
    });
</script>
```